# Printing Google Site - Overlapping Text

Tags: printing, google-sites

My Google Site has two text boxes side by side. When I try to print the site the text merges into one column with the content from one box overlapping with the content of the other rendering it unreadable. Is there a way to keep the page looking like it does on the screen when it prints?

I have attempted to first save as a PDF and to use a different printing extension. I have also tried to change the layout of the printing to landscape. Here's what it should look like:
[image]

Here's what I'm experiencing:
[image]

Comment: Hmm yeah it seems like landscape should have helped you out. I'll see if I can fiddle with it. Could you show your options/source within google sites?

Answer (score 0):

Google Sites (new Sites) doesn't include a built-in feature to offer a print friendly version. Unfortunately at this time there isn't a Google Apps Script service or API to help with this so the work araound is to play with userstyles (CSS) to make a print friendly version.

Here is a link of a tool made by a k8oms, a Diamond Product Expert from the Google Sites Community https://www.k8oms.net/more-info/print-page. Note: I haven't tested yet.

Reference

- https://support.google.com/sites/thread/181065522/how-do-i-print-a-google-sites-page-but-keep-formatting?hl=en